# Writing e2e tests using the selenium-webdriver package for WebDriverJS for node

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on porting tests from webdriver and java to webdriverjs and I'm wondering if someone could help me understand why this works:

```
driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(function() {
  return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    return assert.equal(title, 'webdriver - Google Search');
  });
}, 2000);
```

title correctly contains 'webdriver - Google Search'

And this fails:

```
driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(function() {
  driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    assert.equal(title, 'webdriver - Google Search');
  });
}, 2000);
```

title contains the title from the homepage and not the search results page

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The wait method requires the function return a boolean or a promise that resolves to a boolean in order to work properly. In your first example returning the assert which is a boolean then makes the **then** call a promise that resolves to a boolean (which you are returning to wait) hence wait will work correctly. In the second example your function does not return anything which wait treats as immediate successful resolution, in other words it does not wait at all.